# When using Leaflet and display L.imageOverlay in a loop, how to know which overlays displayed and which did not?

Tags: leaflet

My code has a loop that displays several georeferenced JPGs. A simplified version of the code is shown below.  For each image the code needs to take different action depending whether or not the image loaded.
The listeners fire as they should but I need advice on how to know which jpg_link caused a listener to fire.

```
jpg_overlay[i] = L.imageOverlay(jpg_link[i], jpg_bounds[i]);
// load listener
jpg_overlay[i].on("load", function(event){
    // what jpg_link loaded?
});
// error listener
jpg_overlay[i].on("error", function(event){
    // what jpg_link failed to load?
});
// add jpg to map   
jpg_overlay[i].addTo(map);
```

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#event-target

Comment: JSON.stringify(event.target) throws Uncaught TypeError: cyclic object value

I am digging into that

Comment: I gave up on my original design.  Instead, I am using a function that is called for each overlay.  This seems to be working fine and lets me capture the index values for the overlay images that load and index values for the overlay images that do not load.